# Objective-C and scanning an integer or character to a hex representation

Tags: objective-c, unicode, character-encoding

NSScanner has the instance method `-scanHexInt:` for converting a hexadecimal string representation of an `int` to an `int`. I'd like to invert this: I'd like a method that takes an `int` and returns a hexadecimal representation.

Is there a ready made method in the docs?

[To be more relevant, I'd like to take a string comprising a single kanji and return its unicode point.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation on [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), you'll see that there are several specifiers you can use to get a hexadecimal string representation of a number.  For instance, you could use:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", foo]
```

Comment: More specifically: `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%#02x", [kanjiStr characterAtIndex: 0]]`

Comment: @Jim: Your second answer is what I'm after. (I'd found the first in the docs already but wasn't getting the point.) Thank you.